# Inexplicable NullReferenceException that only occurs in production

Tags: c#, .net

We have an ASP.NET website running which throws a NullReference-exception along with a stacktrace and a line number that is simply impossible. And I can't make heads nor tails from it myself.

It says:

```
Exception at ReportService.GetReport(String reportType) in ReportService.cs:line 1458
```

which is funny, because that is this line:

```
var exports = new List<ReportExport>();
```

Thanks to the (very short) stacktrace, I can see that the error is triggered in the GetReport-function and not in the "GetAllUsers" or "GetAllUsersWithFilter" functions, because I would receive a different error message in my e-mailbox or I would see it pop up in the stacktrace.

So I suspect the line number is wrong, in which case there is only one other possibility and that is this line:

```
  foreach (var userProfile in users) {
      exports.Add(CreateUserProfile(userProfile));
  }
```

But how could `users` ever be null?

Full (albeit simplified) code right here:

```
public function IList<ReportExport> GetReport(string reportType) {
   try {
       IQueryable<UserProfile> users = null;
       switch (reportType) {
           case "abc" : 
             users = GetAllUsersWithFilter();
             break;
           case default:
            users = GetAllUsers();
            break;
      }

      var exports = new List<ReportExport>();
      foreach (var userProfile in users) {
          exports.Add(CreateUserProfile(userProfile));
      }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    SendErrorMail("GetReport has failed", ex); /* I receive this error mail */
  }

function IQueryable<UserProfile> GetAllUsers() {
    try {
      return dbContext.Users.Where(x => x.IsRegistered == true);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       SendErrorMail("GetAllUsers", ex); /* I don't receive this e-mail */
       return null;
    }
}

function IQueryable<UserProfile> GetAllUsersWithFilter() {
    try {
       return GetAllUsers().Where(x => x.ExtraFilter == true);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       SendErrorMail("GetAllUsersWithFilter", ex); /* I don't receive this e-mail */
    }
  }

  function int GetNumberOfSessions(int userId) {
     try {
         return dbContext.Sessions.Count(x => x.UserId == userId);
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         SendErrorMail("GetNumberOfSessions", ex); /* I don't receive this e-mail */
     }
  }

  function ReportExport CreateUserExport(UserProfile user) {
     try {
         var cnt = GetNumberOfSessions(user.Id);
         return new ReportExport() {
           UserId = user.Id,
           NumberOfSessions = cnt
         }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
       SendErrorMail(("CreateUserExport", ex);
     } 
  }
```

Comment: If you are in production then you might be running with optimizations switched on - therefore the line number will be wrong.  But you are catching the Exception then returning null.  You are relying on returning data - which may not be the case in GetAllUsers

Comment: True, but then I'd get an other error mail with a different stacktrace as well, wouldn't I?

Comment: How does SendErrorMail handle multiple incoming messages? Could it hide one from you?

Comment: Just checked and it does only two things: 1) save the error to the log-table in the database + 2) send me an e-mail. So even if it hides the second e-mail from me, it should be in the database probably (which it isn't)

Comment: For GetAllUsersWithFilter - does that even compile (and CreateUserExport, GetNumberOfSessions, GetAllUsersWithFilter).  As you are catching and not returning anything.  What is "function"?

Comment: oh, the "function" shouldn't be there. It's not a part of the C# syntax. I'll edit it in just a minute

Comment: If I decompile my DLL with dotpeek, would the line number be trustworthy then do you think?

Comment: Something I have not tried on optimized code.  I'd be interested to see - but I don't think it wont reflect 100% of what you have in your source.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in production then you might be running with optimizations switched on - therefore the line number will be wrong.

`But how could users ever be null?`

But you are catching the Exception then returning null.  You are relying on returning data - which may not be the case in GetAllUsers.

```
function IQueryable<UserProfile> GetAllUsers() {
    try {
      return dbContext.Users.Where(x => x.IsRegistered == true);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       SendErrorMail("GetAllUsers", ex); /* I don't receive this e-mail */
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely true, but the error mail I get specifies a stacktrace of one line, with "GetReport()" in it. So if the error would occur in GetAllUsers, I should get two mails. One because of the exception in GetAllUsers, which triggers the "null" return value and one because the GetReport function failed. I only get an e-mail that the GetReport function failed, which leads me to believe that GetAllUsers must have succeeded

Comment: The fact you are catching the exceptions in the other functions will hide the exception from the unhandled exception you are receiving.  Or maybe something in SendErrorEmail is wrong and throwing an exception?  Can you post that code?  Also - it doesnt like you are posting the whole code.  Where is dbContext defined?

Comment: True, I haven't posted all of the code because it would take us too far. I just copied the code that generates the error. I should also note that this code seems to work fine 95% of the time.
The DbContext is actually in a different service altogether, I just edited that out for brevity